# Table Column - List of objects containing key/value pairs for "height" and "width"

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I need to store data in a particular manner:

```
    {
      "name": "Table",
      "id": 1,
      "size": [
        {
          "width": "10",
          "height": "100"
        },
        {
          "width": "10",
          "height": "200"
        }
      ]
    }
```

Recap, I need to create a table that can store a list of key/value pairs. Is there a handy way rails creates a migration for this?

I'm specifically asking about the migration step. How can I generate a schema that will support this structure.

Comment: Is the list of key/pair values an individual entry or can you store the whole object in one entry?

Answer (score 1):

You could either store the sizes part in as column with json datatype or decide to make the sizes it's own table (so a table - or piece of furniture - has many sizes).
If you want the json datatype I would run this migration generator:

```
rails generate model FurniturePiece name:string size:jsonb
```

For the second option:

```
rails generate model FurniturePiece name:string
rails generate model Size width:integer height:integer furniture_piece:references
```

Of course you will need to adapt the name of the models and their fields to your need